# T4 Templates and Visual Studio Item Templates

Tags: visual-studio, t4, vsx

Is it possible to create a Visual Studio item template that generates from a T4 template?

My google-fu does not seem powerful enough to yield an answer!

Comment: Do you mean "...that generates a T4 template"? I.e. you want an option "Add New Item..." and then be able to select a t4 template?

Comment: Not quite Kurt,

What I want to do is have the T4 generate a file based on responses to a wizard on "Add new item ..."

Hope that clarifies a little,

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [GAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718948.aspx) for that. It has a (rather limited implementation of) custom T4 host that allows you to use T4 as a template language.

Comment: Thanks Oleg,
This would have worked for me but I decided to do the text transformations in my "New item .." wizard as the GAX solution was a bit heavy for my needs.

Thank you again,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, actually ASP.NET MVC uses this approach when creating View item from Controller item

All the Best
Muse VSExtensions