# Visual Studio Item Template using T4 Templates

Tags: visual-studio, templates, t4, template-engine, t4-toolbox

I want to create a Visual Studio Item Template that generates an Item (for eg. custom .aspx page) in the solution by executing T4 Template while adding it to the solution.
I read the following post : [T4 Templates and Visual Studio Item Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805979/t4-templates-and-visual-studio-item-templates)

Is it possible to implement this without using GAX. I want to start by using a standard project item template and T4 Templates only, which doesn’t require GAX.

Please suggest,

Thanks,

Mayur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is quite possible. You need two pieces to make it work.

Firstly you need to create a template that uses an IWizard implementation to enable you to run custom code.  Here's the documentation for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301(v=vs.100).aspx

Secondly, in your custom IWizard, you need to use T4 via its STextTemplating service.  Here's the documentation for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586947.aspx

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks GarethJ,
Your answer is very useful to me. I have implemented the IWizard. Now I wanted to invoke T4 Templates through VS Extension. But while doing this I am not getting "STextTemplating" and "ITextTemplating" interface in my code (i.e. ITextTemplating t4 = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating;). 
       For this to work, I have added reference to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost" , "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Modeling.10.0"
(plz see nxt comment as can't accommodate all in sngle cment)

Comment: (to be continued from previous comment...)

But still I am not getting this interface. Actually this interface is not in present in "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost". Bt after searching I got only one answer that "ITextTemplating" is in the dll "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost".
      I am writting the code in RunStarted() method of IWizard.
Please suggest a solution to solve this. Am I doing something wrong.
Please reply.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get Service Provider which is mentioned in this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586947.aspx.
        I tried to implement this as :
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

// Get a service provider – how you do this depends on the context:
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider(dte as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);

But it's giving me some Value cannot be null exception.
Am I doing it correct?
Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: The interface is in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0.dll, assumign your'e usign Vissual Studio 2010.  You dont' need the modeling assembly at all.

Comment: You shoudl just be able to call package.GetGlobalService directly with STextTemplating and skip the DTE step altogether.